# model can not be stored as directory in google drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am trying to convert a model to tflite. My code is below:

```
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet')

model.compile('Adam', loss=sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss, metrics=[sm.metrics.iou_score])

history = model.fit(my_generator, validation_data=validation_datagen, steps_per_epoch=50, 
  validation_steps=50, epochs=50)

model.save('drive/MyDrive/small_data_model')

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('drive/MyDrive/small_data_model')
```

I first save the created model in my google drive, and then i try to create the converter. But i get an error:
"SavedModel file does not exist at: drive/MyDrive/small_data_model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}"

The model is saved as a single file without extension, and not as a directory. How can i convert it to tflite in other way?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(...)` may only support local filesystem. So you can copy it locally and run.

As the message indicates, it complains neither `saved_model.pbtxt` nor `saved_model.pb` exists in `drive/MyDrive/small_data_model/`. Please double check it.